# Logical properties of realizability (topoi or McCarty models) defined by alpha-recursion on admissible ordinals

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory, ordinal-computability, realizability

**Setup:**  Let $\alpha$ be an admissible ordinal (viꝫ., one such that $L_\alpha$ is a model of Kripke-Platek set theory), identified as usual with the set of ordinals $<\alpha$.  Then there is a standard theory of computability on $\alpha$, known as “[alpha-recursion theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_recursion_theory)” or “admissible recursion theory”, with many analogies to ordinary (Church-Turing) computability on $\mathbb{N}$.  Possible references for basic facts on the topic include Sacks's book *Higher Recursion Theory* (1990), esp. chapter VII, or the (imho more readable) “Short Course on Admissible Recursion Theory” by Simpson, p. 355–290 in *Generalized Recursion Theory II (Oslo 1977)* edited by Fenstad, Gandy & Sacks (1978).  But just so make sure there's no doubt about the definition, a partial function $f \colon \alpha^{\times r} \dashrightarrow \alpha$ is said to be $\alpha$-partial-recursive (i.e., $\alpha$-partial-recursive *with parameters*) when its graph $\Gamma_f$ is $\Sigma_1(L_\alpha)$ in parameters or, equivalently, when there is a primitive recursive relation $R$ and a parameter $p\in\alpha$ such that $\Gamma_f = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_r,y) \in \alpha^{\times(r+1)} : \exists z\in\alpha.R(x_1,\ldots,x_r,y,z,p)\}$ (the main difference with ordinary computability is that we can't dispense with parameters in general).

Just as for ordinary computability, the $\alpha$-partial-recursive can be given a standard numbering $(\varphi_\varepsilon)_{\varepsilon<\alpha}$ by ordinals $\varepsilon<\alpha$ so that the partial function $(\varepsilon,\gamma) \mapsto \varphi_\varepsilon(\gamma)$ is itself $\alpha$-partial-recursive (“universality”) and such that partial substitution can be performed by primitive recursive functions (“s-m-n”).  So by definining $\varepsilon \bullet \gamma$ as $\varphi_\varepsilon(\gamma)$ (if the latter is defined), we make $\alpha$ into a [partial combinatory algebra (p.c.a.)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+combinatory+algebra) exactly analogous to Kleene's first algebra for the case of ordinary computability on $\mathbb{N}$.

Now one can then apply the general framework of realizability over p.c.a.'s to this situation.  In particular, there is a realizability topos $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ associated to $\alpha$ just like the effective topos is constructed for ordinary recursion on $\mathbb{N}$ (details of the construction are in van Oosten, *Realizability: An Introduction to its Categorical Side* (2008), §2.6).  This topos comes equipped with a distinguished object (maybe call it $\mathring\alpha$) given by $\alpha$ itself, seen as an assembly with $E(\gamma) = \{\gamma\}$ for all $\gamma<\alpha$.  (The natural numbers object $\mathbf{N}$ is a subset of this $\mathring\alpha$.)

Similarly, there is a model of $\mathsf{IZF}$ (intuitionistic Zermelo-Fraenkel) associated to the situation, just like the one constructed by McCarty ([“Realizability and recursive set theory”, *Ann. Pure Applied Logic* **32** (1986) 153–183](https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072%2886%2990050-3)) for ordinary computability: this model can be seen on its own, or within the aforementioned realizability topos $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ (as explained in van Oosten, *op. cit.* §3.5.1).  Maybe call $V(\alpha)$ this model (not an ideal notation as it might be confused with $V_\alpha$, but I can't think of better).

**General question:** Has there been any study of realizability on $\alpha$, or specifically of these topoi $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ or $\mathsf{IZF}$ models $V(\alpha)$ in the mathematical literature?  (I mean, something about $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ that's more specific than the study of *all* realizability topoi.)  Specifically, I wonder if any work has been done in connecting properties of the (intuitionistic!) internal logic of $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ and $V(\alpha)$ to (classical!) recursion-theoretic properties of $\alpha$.

Here's an example of something that can be said along these lines: recall that an admissible ordinal $\alpha$ is said to be **nonprojectible** when $L_\alpha$ is a model of $\Sigma_1$-separation.  Recursion-theoretically, this means that the image of a total $\alpha$-recursive function $\alpha\to\alpha$ is $\alpha$-recursive, or that the projection of an $\alpha$-recursive subset of $\alpha^{\times 2}$ is recursive.  Internally in $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$, this means that the object $\mathring\alpha$ is *omniscient* in the sense that for every function $p\colon\mathring\alpha\to\{0,1\}$ either there is $x$ such that $p(x)=0$ or $p$ is constantly $1$ (see [Escardó, “Infinite sets that satisfy the principle of omniscience in any variety of constructive mathematics”, *J. Symbolic Logic* **78** (2013) 764–784](https://doi.org/10.2178/jsl.7803040) for a discussion of this notion).  I'm not sure whether the analogous result about $\mathring\alpha$ in $V(\alpha)$ holds.

My intuition is that $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ and $V(\alpha)$ should become “more and more classical” in some sense as $\alpha$ becomes more and more recursively large, but of course this can only be true in a limited sense as $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ will never satisfy Excluded Middle (the uniform object $\nabla 2$ will never equal $2$), and in a more restricted sense this is trivial (e.g., the first-order theory of the natural numbers object $\mathbf{N}$ in $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ or $V(\alpha)$ is simply true first-oder arithmetic as soon as $\alpha>\omega$, meaning $\alpha\geq\omega_1^{CK}$).  But maybe I can ask about *propositional* logic or *set theory*:

**Specific question 1:** Is there a propositional formula (ideally a plain propositional formula, i.e., with only prenex universal quantification over $\Omega$, or perhaps a second-order propositional formula) which, interpreted in the internal language of $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$, hold for certain values of $\alpha$ but not all?

**Specific question 2:** Can we characterize the formulae of the language of $\mathsf{IZF}$ which are true on $V(\alpha)$ for closed-unboundedly many $\alpha$?

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.12172) by Carl, Galeotti, and Passmann seems directly relevant. Also Bauer used an infinite-time Turing machine realizability model to show that there can be an injection from Baire space into the natural numbers (as discussed in [these notes](https://www.andrej.com/zapiski/MGS-2022/notes-on-realizability.pdf)).

Comment: I have not seen the notion $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ from any literature, but if my understanding is correct, a variant of $\mathsf{RT}(\alpha)$ appears in Passman's paper [The first-order logic of CZF is intuitionistic first-order logic](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.00486). We may understand Passman's realizability model as a variant of $\mathsf{RT(Ord)}$ (with the allowance of power set operator into the pca) and it does not satisfy the full LEM (and also, full Separation.)

Comment: I and Passman once made joint work about the first-order logic of CZF with large sets, and here I considered a variant of pca augmented with the unbounded search function for $\Sigma_n$-truth predicate. The resulting realizability model (in the sense of $\mathsf{RT}$, and not McCarty's one) should satisfy LEM for $\Sigma_n$-formulas.